# Powershell PSDrive, the folder does not exist

Tags: powershell

Code:

`$pass = "P@ssword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("\administrator",$pass)`

`New-PSDrive  -Name M -PSProvider FileSystem -root "\\server\Folder_for_mapping" -Persistent`

Error:
`The provider does not support the use of credentials. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials.`

The problem comes from my domain network, the shared folder cant bee seen, until I navigate manually to the server, there I will be prompted to login as the computer admin, after then I will be able to see and map the folder with with PSDrive successfully. Is there any possible workaround for this ?

Comment: For what its worth Powershell 3.0 supports credentials for [`New-PsDrive`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you get powershell 3.0 or above you can use `-Credentials` with `New-PsDrive`.

If that is not an option for you, you can map a drive the older way

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("u:", "\\server\share", $false, "domain\user", "password")
```